# how to generate multiple instances of my own server/process in erlang?

Tags: erlang

I wrote a server programe which is planed to use in multi player game. I should be generate multiple instances of my server for every client/player. but i cont able to generate.
I took my server in separate module and I am calling the sever exported function from another module under a process for each client whenever the external aim to connect.

could any one give me some solution other than gen_tcp: server.............

Comment: Can you elaborate this a bit, at present it is rather unclear what you want to do or where your problem is.  What do you mean with your reference to gen_tcp:server??

Comment: Pls elaborate, some sample code would be nice too. Also, please advice one why would spawn/spawn_link, or proc_lib:spawn/spawn_link would not work.

Comment: Please look at http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx for good hints how to improve your questions.  It will reward you with fast and good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to re-think your architecture and identify layers in your system. The first would be connection - ok, it seems you got it. Then you want to present some logic to the user, moreover, you want to give him unique instance of that.. Just spawn it. If it is separate from the rest of the functionality it is going to be trivial. If I ware you, I would read one of Eralng/OTP books (Joe Amstrong, Thomson&Cesarini, Logan recently) to understand nature of Erlang systems and managing processes.